# KeyBoard Navigations

Tags: jquery, uinavigationbar, keyboard-events

i am attempting to have navigation visible on a menu as a user hits a key on their keyboard.

if no menu item is selected, select the first instance of the class "row", if row-focus exists remove current focus and update next instance of row with class "row-focus".

My html is formatted:

```
<div id="group_1386" idgroup="1386" class="group">
  <div class="row feed-group-name row-focus" idgroup="1386"> <span class="text">Winter Is Coming</span></div>
  <div class="thetitles ui-sortable">
    <div id="feed_26451" class="row t-row"><span class="text">#sgluminis - Twitter Search</span> </div>
    <div id="feed_26453" class="row t-row"><span class="text">Twitter / MikeMagician</span> </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="group_1387" idgroup="1387" class="group">
  <div class="row feed-group-name" idgroup="1386"> <span class="text">Summer Is Coming</span></div>
  <div class="thetitles ui-sortable">
    <div id="feed_26451" class="row t-row"><span class="text">Summer Search</span> </div>
    <div id="feed_26453" class="row t-row"><span class="text">Hot Beaches</span> </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

When someone clicks "n" on the keyboard i would like to cycle through elements with the class of "row". I can select the next class using .find(), but it returns more than one row. I can not use .first() because its not always the first. How can I find the next instance of the class row if it is sometimes a sibling, child, but it will always have the class "row".

```
$(document).on("keypress", null, "n", function(){
    if($(".row-focus").length){
        var curr = $("#ind-menu").find(".row-focus");
        var nextActive = $(curr).siblings().next(".row");
        $(curr).removeClass("row-focus");
        $(nextActive).addClass("row-focus");


        //selected.next().find(".row").next().addClass("row-focus");


    } else {
        //alert("nothing selected");
        $("#ind-feeds .row:first").addClass("row-focus");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an element selected in each set in your HTML- how do you expect those to behave when N is pressed? If you want to allow one selection per group:

```
$(document).on("keypress", null, "n", function(){
    if($(".row-focus").length){
        var curr = $("#group_1386").find(".row-focus");
        var allActive = $(curr).parents(".group").find(".row");
        var currIndex = allActive.index(curr);
        var nextActive = allActive.eq(currIndex == allActive.size() - 1 ? 0 : currIndex + 1);

        $(curr).removeClass("row-focus");
        $(nextActive).addClass("row-focus");

    } else {
        $("#group_1386 .row:first").addClass("row-focus");
    }
});
```

[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rs7CE/)

Update that to handle multiple groups however you want. Or if it's one selection per page:

[Another JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rs7CE/1/)

Comment: I was wrong to have the second row-focus in the second group. the intention is to only have one row selected at a time. Your second JSFiddle is spot on.